# Wordpress/Woo how to search in category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In Wordpress / WooCommerce I want to search by Category but somehow I cant get it to work. 
The normal Search works and gives me this url `http://localhost:8888/rwdr/search/[searchkeyword]` 
how does the url look like when searching in a category?

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform2" action="" class="">
    <ul class="radio-ul">
      <li>
        <label for="typBA" class="typ typBA "></label>
        <input name="category" id="typBA" value="BA" type="radio">
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="typBAX7" class="typ typBAX7 "></label>
        <input name="category" id="typBAX7" value="BAX7" type="radio">
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="typBASL" class="typ typBASL "></label>
        <input name="category" id="typBASL" value="BASL" type="radio">
      </li>
    </ul>

    <label for="InputBox">Input Box</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="first" name="s" />
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="x" /> </form>
```

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a search using standard query in your url

`yoursite.com/?post_type=product&taxonomy=product_cat&term=your_category_slug&s=a`

To get the URL, you can build a form like this,

```
<form method="get" action="" role="search">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
    <input type="hidden" name="taxonomy" value="product_cat">
    <input type="hidden" name="term" value="your_category_slug">
    <input type="search" name="s" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me!
somehow only this url is working for me
yoursite.com/search/[searchTerm]?product_cat=[categoryName]
And I have to use " ?product_cat= " as name
<input name="?product_cat=" id="typebax7" value="bax7" type="radio">
is there something wrong with my wordpress/woocommerce?

Comment: dont add ```?``` on your input name,  can you post your whole HTML form?

Comment: This is my form with some jquery stuff
https://jsfiddle.net/linkslegend/p0p1hpcn/
when I remove " ? " the search wont work anymore

Comment: I'm quite lost of what you are trying to accomplish  with the need of jquery? There are so much issue on your form, Just create a simple PHP file paste your form in there and click submit, you'll see the query var pass on the url based on your form, 

I got this query var while submitting your form ```local.com/test.php?s=firstfield&x=&s=secondfield&x=&s=thirdfield&%3Fproduct_cat%3D=bax7```

you can't pass multiple ```s``` parameter, your form should start like this
http://jsfiddle.net/v8wLpa8v/

Comment: I need jquery to filter out the " x " and to automatically fill in the other 3 input fields. For example someone fills in 32x22x7 in input field 1. input field2 gets 32 input field3 gets 22 and input field4 gets 7. And to save the form data for the next page or on reload.
I will test it but I think your form wont work for me, For example i need one normal search form and one with 3 input fields and the radio buttons. And the 3 input fields must generate the same url like the first input field. It may be strange but the form with jquery works exactly the way I want it to work.

Comment: I think the best way is to analyze first what url with query var you are trying to pass using the form, you should also test that url if it gives you the result you desired, I might be able to help you and can provide a form that you would need

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress, I use a plugin called "Search Everything", where you can set if you want to add categories, tags and many other options to the search results. It's pretty easy to use and it works fine to me.